# Angular animations don't work inside mat-tabs after switching back when using custom components

Tags: html, angular, animation, mat-tab

In a very similar situation to the issue Olafvv was observing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64608905/angular-animations-dont-work-inside-mat-tabs-after-switching-back) but running angular 16 and there's a slight nuance in my setup. I have a mat-tab-group containing a number of tabs. The issue I am observing is the same, in that my :enter animations does not work when navigating away from a `mat-tab`, and then back to that same `mat-tab`. The difference for me is that my animation is for a custom sub-component within one of my `app-MyTabContentComponents` and so it's not easy to just drop in the  `ng-template`.

I tried the accepted answer from Olafvv's question, but could not find out where to put the `<ng-template matTabContent` to enable the lazy loading (and therefore the re-triggering of the :enter). I tried locating it:

1. Within the `mat-tab` around my `<app-MyTabContentComponentX` elements, but this resulted in an odd animation where the height of tab 1 reduced to zero, but masking tab 2.
2. As the encasing HTML element within the html of each `MyTabContentComponentX` component.
3. I also tried just using the directive on the `MyTabContentcomponentX` elements, but clearly it's tied to the ng-template class, as this didn't render anything at all!

Here's the HTML in question, and the component the animation is not working on is contained within `MyTabContentComponent3`. To reiterate - the animation works fine the first time the tab is opened.

```
<mat-tab-group class="mat-tab-group" mat-stretch-tabs="false" mat-align-tabs="start" dynamicHeight="true">
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1"> 
    <app-MyTabContentComponent1></app-MyTabContentComponent1>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 2"> 
    <app-MyTabContentComponent2></app-MyTabContentComponent2> 
  </mat-tab> 
  <mat-tab label="Tab 3"> 
    <app-MyTabContentComponent3></app-MyTabContentComponent3> 
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 4">  
    <app-MyTabContentComponent4></app-MyTabContentComponent4> 
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

How can I get this animation to work each time the tab is selected?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is wrap your components in `<ng-template matTabContent></ng-template>`:

```
<mat-tab-group
  class="mat-tab-group"
  mat-stretch-tabs="false"
  mat-align-tabs="start"
  dynamicHeight="true"
>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <app-MyTabContentComponent1></app-MyTabContentComponent1>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 2">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <app-MyTabContentComponent2></app-MyTabContentComponent2>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 3">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <app-MyTabContentComponent3></app-MyTabContentComponent3>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 4">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <app-MyTabContentComponent4></app-MyTabContentComponent4>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Odd animation is caused by `dynamicHeight`, try to remove it:

```
<mat-tab-group
  class="mat-tab-group"
  mat-stretch-tabs="false"
  mat-align-tabs="start"
>
...
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I found that generally works, though some animation still occurs on the height of the contents of each tab, only visible when they are different in overall height, despite removing `dynamicHeight`. This causes a visual artifact where an element is revealed (vertically) as the tab scroll in. Any idea how to prevent that, but retain the tab slide in animation?

Comment: @JamesvanRossum Could you share simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cm7zpy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) prototype which reproduce problem?

Comment: Here's the stackblitz.  

https://shorturl.at/lDQ59

I think what I'm seeing is that as the animation is now working correctly on each load, the overall height of the tab container changes to the size of the tab component (with the button collapsed), which then animates to full size on :enter.  The visual artifact I'm seeing is that the *instant* height change of the tab container when changing tab from one with an expanded button to one without, clips the existing  button and then slowly expands again as the new tab's height expadns with the button animation. Not sure there's an answer!

Comment: I've discovered more, and refined my stackblitz to highlight the true issue I'm having.  See here: https://shorturl.at/lvJRT What I found is that if there is ANY animation declaration in the MyTabContentComponent1 (even a blank animations property under the @Component definition), then when switching back to any tab with components using :enter animations, they no longer appear. Switch to Tab 3, then back to Tab 1, and the button "An appearing button" will have disappeared. Commenting out the `animations: []` in the MyTabContentComponent1 class stopped the button from disappearing.